# Recordset to string not providing all data found in databse

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Background...

So, I wrote a SQL query(query name = qryEmployeeInfo) which shows employee information. The query outputs two columns. The employee ID(header name = employee_ID) and the corresponding employee address(header name = employee_address).

My Access form has a text box(text box name = txtEmployeeID) that I want the user to be able to enter the employee_ID into and have it output the corresponding employee_address into another text box (text box name = txtEmployeeAddress). I also want the employee_address to be in the format of a string variable so I can perform other VBA checks on it later(for example, [if strEmployeeAddress LIKE "California" THEN...something]).

So this is how I approached solving this issue:

```
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select employee_address from qryEmployeeInfo where employee_ID = '" & txtEmployeeID & "'", dbOpenDynaset)

strEmployeeAddress = rs.Fields("employee_address").Value
```

This worked! :) ...kinda

It found the correct data corresponding to the specified employee_ID, but it only pulled some of the text and the rest was cut off.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this new issue?

People were asking for the SQL code I used...here is a version with dummy fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

EA.employee_ID, EA.employee_address

FROM 

(EMPLOYEE_DATA AS EA

INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA_UNION AS EDU
ON (EA.EMPLOYEE_ID = EDU.EMPLOYEE_ID)
AND (EA.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = EDU.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS))

INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA_HAMPTON AS EDH
ON (EA.EMPLOYEE_ID = EDH.EMPLOYEE_ID)
AND (EA.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = EDH.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS)

WHERE

EA.ADDRESS_CD IN ('10', ‘12’)
AND EA.SUB_ADDRESS_CD IN ('11', ‘15’)
AND EDU.TASK_CD IN ('144','145','150')
AND EDH.TASK_CD IN ('119','120');
```

I get several correct results from this query in sql assistant...but they are cut off when I go into Access for some reason.

Thoughts?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. In what way was it cut of?

Comment: Please add the SQL of `qryEmployeeInfo` to the question.

Comment: I unfortunately can not provide my SQL code because the database is protected due to proprietary concerns. I have changed the names of this VBA to make an example question for this forum. But, to give you some more information in the "employee_address" are large text fields comprised of maybe 1000 characters or more. When I run the exact same query in SQL Assistant and in tableau I get the exact same data found in teradata. Then when I run "strEmployeeAddress = rs.Fields("employee_address").Value" I only get the last maybe 100 characters. Any know why that would be?

Comment: You should still show SQL statement even if you have to use dummy field names, as you already did for one SQL statement.  Does Access query object pull full data?

Comment: June7, you're correct...for some reason Access is not pulling all the data :(
I'll provide the query, one sec.

Comment: Exactly where is data - Access or some other db platform? If other, how is Access connecting to data?

Comment: Its doing a 'external data' ODBC connection to teradata.

Comment: What is the length of the returned *address* field? Find with `LEN()` function in Access SQL or VBA.

Comment: Parfait, it appears to be variable...sometimes 50 characters and sometimes over 100.

Comment: I'm going to try and speak with my mentor at work tomorrow and see if he can see the issue...if we figure it out ill circle back.